# cassandra lastupdated(auto_now), lastaccessed and created(auto_now_add)

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, gocql, cassandra-node-driver

Is there a way we can auto update the columns creation and last updated/accessed timestamp?

We can use `toTimestamp(now())` function to store the creation time. But do we have a function like `writetime(name)`, which is used to get the last modified time? Is there a similar function for reading the creation and accessed-time?

Is there a way I can get all the three timestamps `lastupdated`/`lastaccessed` and `created` timestamp auto-generated and stored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a [writetime](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__description_unique_39) function, but it only operates on non-primary key columns.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT name,description,writetime(description)
FROm bookbyname WHERE name='Patriot Games';

 name          | writetime(description) | description
---------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Patriot Games |       1442340092257821 | Jack Ryan saves England's next king, and becomes the target of an IRA splinter terrorism cell.
```

Cassandra does not keep track of last accessed/read, or anything like that.

In Cassandra the last write wins, so last updated and created are going to be the same.  But if you had a column that you know had changed, and one that you know had not changed, you could get the write times of both, and then you'd have your updated and created times.

Comment: The solution that I can think is to have read query and set the columns for last accessed/updated and created by creating the UDT (as frozen is required for it). Even if I add the dummy column it is set to nil by default and WRITETIME will not work. I wanted to have single exec() but it seems that two steps are mandatory.

Comment: So, in cassandra if I concurrently increment a table cell that has the value of "10" twice, will I end up with "11" or "12"?